# looking for NHiberneate bi-directional relations example

Tags: c#, nhibernate, bidirectional-relation

I am looking for NHiberneate bi-directional relations examples to see how the xml markup and POCO classes look like, and also how to update the bi-directional relationship .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one:
http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/NHibernate-inverse3dtrue-and-cascade3dsave-update-demo.aspx

And here's a more elaborate one:
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild

Comment: I read thru your link  http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild  but fail to reproduce the part which use not-null="true", and then use casade="all" . I cannot save use with just a flush() call . Also , the children Collection inside the parent cannot remove any child (I checked using the Collection Contains() method , which return false but it is definitely inside the collection ) . Does anyone has a working example use Iesi's HashSet , and <set> instead of bag ?

Comment: Could you post another question with a sample model hierarchy that you're trying to persist and an example of how you're trying to save it? It's difficult to give you pointers without having a concrete example of how you're modelling/using your objects.

Comment: thanks for staying with me. The new thread is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068666/problem-with-nhibernate-one-to-many-relationship-collection-with-cascade